# Upper triangular matrix and hermitian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

1. Let $U$ be the space of all upper triangular matrices and $V$ the space of all Hermitian matrices.
   Find $\dim(V/ (V \cap U)$. So $\dim(V)=n+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ and $\dim(V\cap U)=n$ (there are diagonal matrices). So $\dim(V/(V \cap U)=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$. Is that correct?
2. Find all smiliarity equivalence classes of nilpotent matrices in $Mat_6(K)$.
   I counting all Jordan canonical form and I've got $11$ classes.

Comment: Yes, both answers are correct.

Comment: Thank's. One more question, I don't wannt to make new one. Is geometric multiplicity always bigger then 0 ?

Comment: Yes, geometric multiplicity is always bigger than $0$.